# Fullpage Responsive Absolute Image

Tags: javascript, html, css, optimization, responsive

I want to ask you how to make child1 responsive for different screen sizes, on width and height. Actually I can set the width with queries but height is may oversized or way lower than it supposed to be in regards to window.documentheight.scrollheight which is total page height.

```js
<main className="mainbg">
    <div className="child1">
              a component along the page. from top to bottom. see css.
    </div>
  <div className="child2">
             otherchilds.
    </div>
  <div className="child3">
              otherchilds.
    </div>
    {/*/ <Awesomeslider> /*/}
    <div className="child4">
         firstslide
    </div>
    <div className="child5">
        rightslide
    </div>
    {/*/ <Awesomeslider/> /*/}
</main>

//Slider with React.js = awesomeslider
```

```css
.mainbg {
    width: 100vw;
    height: fit-content;
    display: block;
    background: linear-gradient(/*/ some gradient along the page including sliders /*/);
}
.child1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 50vw;              /*/ will be setted as it will be fit along full page from main to child2, but it must be hidden in child3 /*/
    margin: auto;
}
.child2 {
    width: 100vw;
    height: fit-content;            /*/ child1 will be visible here /*/
}

.child3 {
    width: 100vw;
    height: fit-content;            /*/ child1 will be visible here /*/
}

.child4 {
    width: 100vw;
    height: fit-content;            /*/ child1 will be visible here /*/
}

.child5 {
    width: 100vw;
    height: fit-content;              /*/ child1 won't be visible here /*/
}
```

Also, can we import some variables from JavaScript to CSS, or change height on JS side with
`child.style.height ="window.documentheight.scrollheight"

But it must be realtime, JS gonna get the total page height then it will be applied to the function that change of child1.`

Comment: This type of question is best presented as rendered HTML and CSS. React code is difficult to troubleshoot here.

Comment: Protip: A class is a set of like things. Use _one_ for all that repeating CSS.

Comment: Thanks for protip, I just made it like that to show every piece at clear. I also added React, in case of if someone would drop a soliton based on react.